# Enum string parse and get custom attribute assign to array

Tags: c#, performance, array, .net, enum

I wrote a code which:
- parse string to my enum
- get description from enum 
- assign to string[] array

```
private readonly string[] allowed;

public AuthorizeRoles(params object[] arrayParam)
{
    allowed = (arrayParam.Select(myField => Enum.Parse(typeof (MyEnum), myField.ToString()))
        .Select(temp => temp.GetType().GetField(temp.ToString()))
        .Select(field => GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof (DescriptionAttribute)))).OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
        .Select(attribute => attribute.Description)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Could you tell me if it possible to improve this code for better efficiency and clean code.

Comment: Is it not performing well?

Comment: It's okay, but I'm looking forward to improve this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall code seems OK then I highlight just few minor issues (and I propose a slightly bigger change to simplify code).

**1.**

```
public AuthorizeRoles(params object[] arrayParam)
```

`arrayParam` is not a descriptive name, what is it? List of roles? Make it clear changing name to - for example - `roles`.

**2.**

```
arrayParam.Select(myField => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), myField.ToString()))
```

You're converting each `arrayParam` item to a string however you're not doing any check, if one of them is `null` then code will fail with `NullReferenceException` for a long line packed with a lot of code. Not so helpful. You may check in advance with:

```
if (arrayParam.Any(x => x == null))
    throw new ArgumentException("...");
```

Otherwise just let `Enum.Parse()` fail and use `Convert.ToString(myField)` won't throw for `null` input. Note that if type is restricted to be `string` or `MyEnum` then you may change your function definition accordingly:

```
public AuthorizeRoles(params string[] arrayParam)
public AuthorizeRoles(params MyEnum[] arrayParam)
```

Note that a weird user may have this:

```
object[] pars = null; // It may be a function argument...
AuthorizeRoles(pars);
```

Then you should also check if `arrayParam` is `null` itself:

```
if (arrayParam == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("arrayParam");
```

**3.**

```
.Select(field => GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute))))
.OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
```

In this case you do not need `OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()` because values are just of one type, it's a minor optimization but I think it's better to don't confuse future readers and `Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()` or directly `(DescriptionAttribute)` before `GetCustomAttribute()`.

---

Now if it's allowed to change little bit your code I think it may be simplified. Pick this part:

```
arrayParam.Select(myField => Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), myField.ToString()))
    .Select(temp => temp.GetType().GetField(temp.ToString()))
```

First you convert input values to strings then you parse them to have `MyEnum` and finally you convert them back to string to use them with `GetField()`. One step should be omitted:

```
arrayParam.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x))
    .Select(x => typeof(MyEnum).GetField(x))
```

`GetCustomAttribute()` is a custom helper function, if you change it to this prototype:

```
private static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(FieldInfo field)
    where T : Attribute
```

Then last few lines of your code may be simplified (cast is not required and last `.Select()` may be merged in previous one). Note that with the generic argument `T` we don't even need a `Type` parameter (you can obtain type using `typeof(T)`).

Then if we rewrite whole function for an overview we have something like this:

```
public AuthorizeRoles(params object[] roles)
{
    if (roles == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("roles");

    if (roles.Any(x => x == null))
        throw new ArgumentException("...");

    allowed = roles.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x))
        .Select(x => typeof(MyEnum).GetField(x))
        .Select(x => GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(x).Description)
        .ToArray();    
}
```

The two `.Select()` *may* be merged but I'd not scarify readability just to keep code shorter and a minor performance gain (after all we're working with Reflection here...) You may also want to add some checks before the second `.Select()` or inside `GetCustomAttribute<T>()` to throw a meaningful error message if one of given values is not a valid `enum` element.

Comment: I'd been first if I hadn't been distracted, I was just writing the same :-)